# How to sudo on a computer using ssh inside a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I'm trying to run a bash script that has:

```
ssh -l <username> <compname> 'sudo yum -y install expect'
```

I get the error:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

on some computers but on others the process runs smooth. How can I prevent this?

Comment: superuser.com might be a better place for this question

Comment: The question *is* programming related because it is in a script.  That is enough to make it valid for SO.  No mere user would need to know this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `-t` flag to force a tty to be allocated:

```
ssh -t -l <username> <compname> 'sudo yum -y install expect'
```